Why won't Arcade recognize related table in Field Maps app?
I have a Field Maps application to inventory trees.
The application's associated web map has the following features associated with it:
Layers

trees

Tables

Maintenance
Inspections
trees_related

I created the trees_related table to allow for certain fields in the Field Map app to auto-calculate (genus, species, functional group, native/non-native), based on a shared commonname field.
Initially, I had a related table called names_genus_species that had the same information as trees_related. I preferred the brevity of the name trees_related, so went with that table instead.
I have four fields in my trees point layer that are auto-calculated based on fields in the related table. Originally, I wrote the expressions to use the names_genus_species table. All four expressions are structurally identical. The only difference between them is the reference to the relevant field in the related table. For instance, the expression to evaluate for species name:
var related_table = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "names_genus_species", ["commonname", "species"], true);
var common_name = $feature.commonname;
var matched_feature = First(Filter(related_table, "commonname = @common_name"));
return iif(!IsEmpty(matched_feature), matched_feature['species'], 'Unknown');


This works fine. It continues to work despite the fact that the names_genus_species table is NO LONGER part of the web map $datastore. Again, I removed it and replaced it with trees_related.
However, when I use the same code structure and replace the related table name so that the expression contains the table that actually is part of the $datastore in the web map, the code returns an error. For example, when I run:
var related_table = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "trees_related", ["commonname", "species"], true);
var common_name = $feature.commonname;
var matching_features = Filter(related_table, "commonname = @common_name");
var matched_feature = First(matching_features);
return iif(!IsEmpty(matched_feature), matched_feature['species'], 'Unknown');


I am met with this error:

Test execution error: Execution error - Invalid parameter. Verify test
data.

What might be going on here?

$datastore is accessing the feature service that at $feature is in, not all available layers/tables in the map. Try changing your source to $map instead and see if that solves your problem.
